# Weka attribute problems

Tags: csv, dataset, data-mining, weka

I am currently using Weka and I am having a problem with preprocessing the data. You see when I got the data some of the data is telling me that the attribute is neither numeric nor nominal. What do I have to do to fix the data that has that error.

I tried many preprocessing techniques, but nothing worked.

Comment: What data type were you expecting? If numeric: did you check the values in that column whether they are actually numeric? If nominal: when loading from a CSV file, columns with many different categorical values get imported as STRING rather than NOMINAL. In that case, you can use the [StringToNominal](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToNominal.html) filter to change the type.

Comment: That's a thing I tried that, but it didn't work. All that it kept saying that it is neither numeric nor nominal. Besides the dataset I am trying to do is Amazon Business Analyst Dataset.

Comment: What does the header of your ARFF file look like and which attribute are you trying to convert?

Comment: It's a csv file

Comment: Save it as ARFF then you can see thr column types.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. The dataset I am using is called Amazon Business Research Analyst Dataset, and its attributes are Road_Traffic_Desnity, Weather, and Time_Ordered.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? If you can load the data in the Explorer as CSV then you can save it as ARFF (the native Weka data format).

Comment: I saved the it as a ARFF file, and it still gave me the same results.

Comment: I didn't say saving as ARFF would solve the problem, but that you can look at the header (and post it as as well).